# "interesting tags" on the "newest questions" page are missing counts

Tags: support, tag-watching

On SO, when viewing the "newest questions" page, I see some of the questions are highlighted due to them having one of my "interesting" tags.  However, the list of interesting tags on the right side of that page have no counts beside them, just an `x`.  I thought they used to have the number of questions on the page with that tag.  Shouldn't they?

(This is with Firefox 3.5.2-2 on Fedora 11, if that matters.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ooooh.  Those "x"'s are for deleting the interesting tags, not multipliers like the "x"'s near the tags down lower.   That wasn't ... obvious ... to me, at least.

Perhaps giving a shaded background circle in the same size as what shows up when you hover over them?  That might help differentiate them visually...

Comment: Don't the X's show up with a red circle, when you hover over the X?

Comment: Yeah, ''when you hover over it'', but I hadn't done that... looking at it, it looked like the multiplier "x" from numerous other places on the site, and figured it carried the same meaning.  After posting the question, and going back to them for the umpteenth time, I happened to hover over them --- and that's where the "Ooooh" came from.

I had modelled the visual interface of the site as "An 'x' indicates how many times something has occurred" and that wasn't what it meant in this case.

Answer (score 0):

They never have for me. The only place I've seen the tag counts you're talking about are in the actual questions.